# What role does the capacitor and the resistor play in the following circuit?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, rectifier

I opened up an LED light bulb at my home and sketched its circuit diagram as follows:
[image]

I don't understand what the initial 470n capacitor connected to the live wire and the final 100ohm resistor connected to the neutral wire does.

Comment: 1000 k is 1 M in grown-up units.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It would be 1Meg in SPICE; LTSPICE will interpret 1M exactly as 1m, since it is case insensitive.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati That's a "feature" of Berkeley SPICE from the mid-1970s and it still catches young players from time to time. A consequence of it being written in FORTRAN, I suppose.

Comment: @Lorenzo: That's a serious gotcha in LTSPICE if it interprets M and m the same.  However, that has nothing to do with my point, which was that in engineering the multiplier is adjusted so that there are 1 to 3 digits left of the decimal.  1000 k should be written 1 M.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I didn't know its origin, but yep, I know it's a "gotcha" in any SPICE simulator I've encountered.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yes, I got that, but I meant to play devil's advocate for the OP: writing 1000k in SPICE is the basic workaround used by people when they realize that 1M is interpreted as 1mOhm. Discovering that it is possible to use 1Meg is an advanced topic :-)

Comment: Except, for some reason, capacitors. Manufacturers seem to be allergic to nanoFarads. You can buy a 10,000 picoFarad capacitor, and you can buy a 0.01 microFarad capacitor, but no one sells a 10 nanoFarad cap.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Wow, thanks. You are indeed right. I used 1000k as a workaround. It is nice to know that 1Meg works in LTSpice.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Yep! And even 10mF are often written as 10,000microF!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a cheapo [capacitive dropper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply) power supply.

The impedance of the cap limits the current without wasting too much power into heat. R1 discharges C1 to protect you from shock when you unplug the bulb. R2 limits inrush current.

Comment: R2 also provides a convenient way of measuring current, and relatively safe since it's on the low side, but that's probably not its main purpose. It'll limit surge current to 2.5Arms - this is probably JUST below the single cycle surge rating (Issm) of those diodes.

Comment: In case you are interested, the rectifier diodes used were 1N4007 with a Non-Repetitive Peak Forward Surge Current (Ifsm) of 30A.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The low side? It's AC!

Comment: Yes, the low side : neutral has a potential close to Earth. Note that I did NOT say the negative side.

Comment: Screw on bulb usually has neutral connected to the screw and live on the tip (for fingers safety) but others like bayonet/GU10 can be put in both ways... Anyway. Just nitpicking.

Comment: Neutral is many countries has a potential close to earth (at least in the absence of a fault), but is still treated as a live conductor in the regs with regard to insulation. There is at least one of the Nordic? countries that does three phase delta to domestic users with 240V between the phases and NO neutral as such. In that situation both ends of the lamp really are live....

Comment: @DanMills: Also check railroad circuits.

Comment: Precisely ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDY-0ijiOEQ